# Why is option not defined in this python3 calculator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been learning python3 for around two hours and I decided to create a little program that adds, divides or multiplies numbers. For some reason, the option is supposedly 'not defined' in this program when the user clearly inputs something for it.

https://pastebin.com/VBB2arkr

```
def ask_numbers():
    num1 = input("Please enter a number:  ")
    num2 = input("Please enter another number:  ")

def add_div_mul():
    option = input("Would you like to divide, multiply or add your numbers?")

def multiply_nums(num1, num2):
    numsmultiplied = float(num1) * float(num2)
    print(numsmultiplied)

def add_nums(num1, num2):
    numsadded = float(num1) + float(num2)
    print(numsadded)

def divide_nums(num1, num2):
    numsdivided = float(num1) / float(num2)
    print(numsdivided)

ask_numbers()
add_div_mul()
if option == "multiply": multiply_nums()
if option == "add": add_nums()
if option == "divide": divide_nums()
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/291978/3001761

Comment: The scope of option exists only inside the function, it doesnt exist outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return and pass the variables

```
def ask_numbers():
    num1 = input("Please enter a number:  ")
    num2 = input("Please enter another number:  ")
    return num1, num2

def add_div_mul():
    return input("Would you like to divide, multiply or add your numbers?")

def multiply_nums(num1, num2):
    numsmultiplied = float(num1) * float(num2)
    print(numsmultiplied)

def add_nums(num1, num2):
    numsadded = float(num1) + float(num2)
    print(numsadded)

def divide_nums(num1, num2):
    numsdivided = float(num1) / float(num2)
    print(numsdivided)

num1, num2 = ask_numbers()
option = add_div_mul()
if option == "multiply": multiply_nums(num1, num2)
if option == "add": add_nums(num1, num2)
if option == "divide": divide_nums(num1, num2)
```